# NavigationController from Modal View?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using a Navigation Controller. My RootViewController pushes a number of views but it also presents a modal view. That modal view presents a tableView. So what I'm trying to do is figure out of I can push the Navigation Controller across the modal view, then use it from that modal view to push the view with the tableView? or barring that, is there a way to implement a second Navigation Controller from the modal view?

The real issue is that I want to present the view with the tableView using a right to left transition, which of course is not available with modal views.

I have this code that SORT OF provides the right to left transition used by the Navigation Controller:

```
NewViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:newViewController animated:NO];

CGSize theSize = CGSizeMake(320, 460);
newViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 + theSize.width, 0 + 20, theSize.width, theSize.height);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animationID" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
newViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 + 20, 320, 460);
[UIView commitAnimations];
[newViewController release];
```

The problem is that the OldViewController (the one calling the NewViewController) disappears immediately so the NewViewController transitions across a blank screen, instead of covering the OldViewController.

Comment: You can do `UIView animations` with `presentModal...animated:false`. Is there any reason to overriding the `presentmodal...` animation?

Comment: I'm trying to get the right-to-left animation transition that's only possible with the Navigation Controller.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presenting a UIViewController modally creates a whole new navigation stack. You could do something like this:

```
//Create the view you want to present modally
UIViewController *modalView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
//Create a new navigation stack and use it as the new RootViewController for it
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:modalView];
//Present the new navigation stack modally
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
//Release
[modalView release];
[nav release];
```

This can be done because UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController. When the new view is loaded, you can use it however you wish (push another view on top of it, us UIView animations like Waqas suggeste, etc').

I hope I got your question correctly. Do tell if I didn't.

Comment: Thanks. What I have now is this: [RootViewController1] --> presents [ModalViewController2] --> presents [ViewController3 with Modal Transition]. What I want to have now is this: [RootViewController1] --> presents [ModalViewController2] --> presents [Pushed ViewController3 with Navigation Controller Transition]. Is that do-able using the methods you've spelled out?

Comment: It Should do the trick. Come to think of it, I believe there is an easy solution here - you could present the first view modally, then push the table view on it in the viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Also, if there is delay because of the intermediate view, you can try and push it modally with Animated:NO.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look, though it seems altogether cleaner to do an animation as i have in code above, provided i can get the look right.